# WebApi o mesmo Model do backoffice

Tags: asp.net-core-web-api

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver uma camada WebAPI para um Front em angular. Quero aceder às tabelas do backoffice e não quero criar tabelas para a WebAPI.

Meu projeto BO c/os Models e o Data, seguem aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1BDX.jpg e https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJaEC.jpg

Meu projeto WebAPI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTuDp.jpg

Não devo criar o /Data? Como acesso ao do controller ao projeto backoffice?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Luís, seja bem vindo ao SO em Português. De modo geral, criar modelos é importante em linguagens fortemente tipadas, pois define bem as estruturas de dados que você está a trabalhar. Sua dúvida não está muito clara, poderia detalhar melhor a pergunta? Explique o que deseja fazer, o que já tentou e, se possível, adicione exemplos da modelagem/tabelas.

Comment: Por favor edite a pergunta, adicionando as informações diretamente nela. Podes usar [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/373568/edit). O ideal é que todas as informações relevantes estejam na pergunta, já que os comentários são limitados e dificultam a leitura de código.